# Streaming data from android phone to computer via USB without ADB

Tags: android

I want to use my android smartphone as a usb camera of sorts.

Just downloading an app won't do, as I intend on doing something very specific which requires me to program things myself.

The problematic part seems to be transferring the data via the usb connection.

After a lot of extensive googling, I still haven't found a way to **stream** anything via the usb without ADB

I'm looking for some direction as to how I can stream data from the smartphone to the computer via USB.

Note that performance isn't really an issue. The "video" can be 4fps  200x200 greyscale for my purposes. I just can't count on having an internet connection.

Comment: You should look at [AOA](http://source.android.com/devices/accessories/protocol.html) and use [libusb](http://libusb.info) on the computer.

Comment: @rom1v thank you! I haven't come across AOA during all of my googling. Now that I've googled it, I'm only missing one thing - you wouldn't happen to know where I might find an example of reading data sent via AOA with `libusb`?

Comment: Why not just [network over USB](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb)

Comment: You can use USB tethering (see [my answer here)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66256/how-to-traverse-camera-from-device-via-adb-to-my-ubuntu).